# How to reload html tag object data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I want to reload svg file when `scrollTop` reach at specific location. Svg added to the html page using `object` tag.

*html code*

```
<section class="section" id="svg-scroll">
.....
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://reussis.com/demo/vardan/svg/icons_-04.svg"></object>
....
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://reussis.com/demo/vardan/svg/icons_-03.svg"></object>
.....</section>
```

*script*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    svg_scroll_function();
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
            svg_scroll_function();
    }); 
})
function svg_scroll_function() {
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= ($('#svg-scroll').offset().top -80)) {

        $('object').reload();// Here i want to reload something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one time only, set a `first_time` var in root to true;

```
var first_time = true; //this should be outside of scroll function
...
if(first_time){
  $('object').each(function(index,el){
    $(el).attr('data', $(el).attr('data'));
  });
  first_time = false;
}
```

Comment: If i want to load only once ,should I set any count?

Comment: you need a flag to run it one time only. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

In order to reload the files in your `objects`, you have to grab references to those elements and then update their `data` attribute.

In the example below, we grab every `object` in the DOM and reload them by resetting their `data` attributes to the value that they already have:

```
var objects = document.getElementsByTagName("object");

for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {

    var obj = objects[i];

    obj.data = obj.data // will trigger update
}
```

If, instead of updating every `object` in the DOM, you wish to update only one, then give that object an `id` attribute (i.e. `swf-obj`) and set its `data` attribute to its current value:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("swf-obj");

obj.data = obj.data; // trigger update
```